# Can't install fbgraph module in play framework

Tags: facebook-graph-api, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, fb-graph

So I am trying to install the fbgraph module to test it out in play framework. According to the documentation (http://www.playframework.org/modules/fbgraph-0.3/home), I should download the fb graph module and then install it using:

```
play install fbgraph-{version}
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: install (similar: initialize, inspect, shell)
[error] Not a valid project ID: install
[error] Not a valid configuration: install (similar: optional)
[error] Not a valid key: install (similar: initialize, dist, stage)
[error] install
[error]        ^
```

Is there any better way to do this? A Maven dependency may be?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a plugin for play 1 with play 2:
http://www.playframework.org/modules

> These modules are for the Play 1.x series only.

Play 1 is incompatible with play 2.
There you find plugins for play 2: 
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules

Maybe you are compfortable with just http://restfb.com/.

You can add in /project/Build.scala

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
     "com.restfb" % "restfb" % "1.6.11" //this line should be new
)
```